# PowerApps login issues on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, powerapps

I'm unable to use PowerApps in Chrome, but am able to use it successfully in Edge. The issue manifests itself in two places (as far as I can tell), but it's concerned with logging in to PowerApps on Chrome.

If I go to create.powerapps.com, no matter how many times I log in, I'm presented with the 'Sign in required: We need you to sign in again. Please click the button to continue'. The 'More' error is as follows:

```
Unable to obtain access token for resource
'https://management.core.windows.net/'. Error from ADAL.js: login_required 
(AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The 
cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to 
Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and 
the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security 
zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
```

I've read through many posts regarding this error, and believe I've followed all the suggestions (e.g. allowing 3rd party cookies for create.powerapps.com). Note that this issue isn't present when using Microsoft Edge.

The second instance of this issue, is when accessing a SharePoint page which has an embedded PowerApps in a webpart. On Edge, I might need to click on the 'login' button on the webpart when first using the site, but from that point on the PowerApp functions as required. On Chrome however, I click on the login button within the webpart, a popup is generated momentarily, which then disappears and nothing happens. I'm entirely unable to view/use the embedded PowerApp in SharePoint with Chrome.

This seems to be somewhat of a systemic issue with PowerApps. Is there a documented, proven resolution for this issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue ? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I discontinued using PowerApps shortly after making this post as it seemed too buggy and restrictive for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable "Block third-party cookies" in Chrome settings.

Answer (score 0):

Different Microsoft logins, when some are linked to ADFS or Azure AD, works exceptionally bad. I've found a solution that seems to work consistently well well on Chrome when forced to work on Microsoft environments (Office365 / SharePoint / PowerApps).

For every MS login you need, click your Chrome profile and select 'Add' under 'Other profiles'. You can have one Chrome profile for each client company you work for.

Now, switch easily between profiles and never experience the problem again. You can work simultaneously with many profiles, one window for each. A similar solution is available in Edge.